# TestCaseSource is executing multiple times though only one test case is being executed

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm using NUnit 3 for my testcase execution. Here
ContextualTestData becomes my test data reader and passes it to test case
`

```
public class ContextualTestData<T> where T : class
    {
        public static T[] ExtractData()
        {
         // Read xml data and serialize then return

        }
}
```

`
Now I have 3 test cases referring this(ContextualTestData) generic method to retrieve data

```
[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(ContextualTestData<Shipping>), nameof(ContextualTestData<Shipping>.ExtractData))]
    public void Should_ExecuteShippingInformationOnce(Shipping shipping)
    {
        // Arrange
        // Act
           Execute(shipping)
        // Assert
    }
```

Similar as above for Order and Sales.

During test case execution of one of these test cases , nunit fires ContextualTestData class 3 times rather than once ie., when shipping test case is executed, it fires first Order then sales and finally shipping,then passes the shipping data to the shipping test case, though first two executions doesn't fire its respective testcases but then it's a wasted execution. Is there anyway to restrict the execution of ContextualTestData w.r.t to the test case that is currently in execution.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit first discovers (i.e. constructs) test cases and subsequently executes them. Your `TestCaseSource` plays a part in the construction of the cases.

Filtering of test cases is very general. It can operate on the test name, categories or properties of the test case. So, in order to work, all the cases have to first be constructed. For that reason, it's advised that you don't perform resource-intensive work in your `TestCaseSource` method.

There are two approaches to solving your problem and you can even use both of them together...

1. The 3.11 release of NUnit will included the ability to use **pre-filtering**. Pre-filtering takes place before your tests are discovered and is limited to selecting specific namespaces, classes or methods for inclusion. Other classes and methods are simply ignored. Unfortunately, this feature is not yet released and is only available when using NUnitLite. Implementations are planned for the console runner and the vs adapter.
2. Minimize the work being done by your test-case source. You could do this by **not** serializing the XML data in the `TestCaseSource`. Instead, simply retrieve the individual data items (which would either need to be in separate files or at least on separate lines in a single file and pass it to your test as a string. Let your test call a method that interprets the data.

Comment: hi @charlie are you able to expound on # 2 with a little bit of code example currently i'm returning an IEnumerable from the TestCaseSource data to use with the test case and test case discovery is taking a very long time to discover test cases, I've updated this and also tried different settings still taking over 13min after code change for test discovery to happen.